# Cygwin Does Not run .py and .sh File Created in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, shell, visual-studio-code, terminal, cygwin

I am running Cygwin terminal in Visual Studio Code (2019), and I tried to run hello.sh and hello.py file, but nothing gets printed out in the terminal. No error message either. I also tried to open a Cygwin terminal outside of Visual Studio, nothing gets printed out either.

However, I created the same files from Pycharm in a venv directory, and copied the files into my Cygwin directory -- it worked.

code in hello.py file:

```
print("hello world")
```

code in hello.sh file:

```
echo hello world
```

I run these files with the same commands in all of the aforementioned terminals:

```
./hello.sh
python hello.py
```

Output when I use hello.py and hello.sh files generated and copied from Pycharm:

```
hello world
```

Otherwise nothing goes on when run these two files from Cygwin.

I wonder how this happened and how to generate .py files and .sh that will work directly in VS Studio.

I have seen other threads mentioning a "command not found" error when running .sh files. It is not my case, since no error gets printed out.

Thanks!

Comment: Where VS is looking for the program to execute ? I doubt it is Cygwin aware and knows that needs to run the cygwin version of bash or python

Comment: Maybe the first step is to run something like `diff hello.py pycharm/hello.py`

Comment: @matzeri Hi, I have configured VS code to use Cygwin as the integrated terminal.

Comment: @Bec Zhao -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I tested this process on my computer, and it is recommended that you could refer to the following:

1. Please ensure that the download and installation of "[Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-dir) Terminal" is correct.
2. Before using this terminal to execute a file, please go to the parent folder where the file is located.

   1). Execute the "`hello.sh`" file in the "`Cygwin`" terminal outside of VSCode:

   [image]

   2). Use the "`Cygwin`" terminal to execute the "`hello.sh`" file in VSCode:

   [image]

   3). Use the "`Cygwin`" terminal in VSCode to execute the "`hello.py`" file:

   [image]

In addition, in order to use the "`Cygwin`" terminal in VSCode, I used the following settings in "`settings.json`":

> "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "...:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe",